# Is it more performant to defer CSS to :hover if possible?

Tags: css

Consider the following:

```
.element {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.element:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

To me, these two CSS snippets are identical. The cursor is only seen when hovering the element. Either method of decorating the cursor works equally well.

I'm curious how this works under the hood. Is there a preference here for using one or the other? If so, why?

Comment: For your specific example I see no need for the `:hover` option.

Comment: its really only for overriding whatever the default cursor is (which you could very well do just by adding a class to the link).  But if you think about it, you are saving a few characters and dom parsing by just using :hover rather than a class.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to move the cursor over an element without moving the cursor over the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do some analysis here. The only difference is the `hover` pseudo-element, which declaratively indicates to change the rendering in response to user actions.

The cursor property description in the [CSS3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#cursor) contains the following:

> This property specifies the type of cursor to be displayed for the
>   pointing device when over the element's border, padding, and content.

This can be interpreted as modifying the cursor as a response to a mouseover event.

On the other end the :hover pseudo selector description in the  [CSS3 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#useraction-pseudos) contains the following:

> A visual user agent could apply this pseudo-class when the cursor (mouse pointer) hovers over a box generated by the element.

This applies a whole set of properties to the element in question as a response to a mouseover event, which could mean repainting some of the portions of the screen if you had some other properties in there, but since you are only setting the mouse cursor a repaint should not happen, so using hover with cursor can be considered as **syntactic over-complication** for your specific example, since they do exactly the same.

For your concrete example there should not be any significant performance difference since in both cases a mouse over event is raised, and an event handler in native code applies the new cursor. A repaint does not happen.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you only need the :hover if you want more actions or different pointers than the default when hovering the item, like these:

```
.element.crosshair {
    cursor: crosshair;
}

.element.help {
    cursor: help;
}

.element.wait {
    cursor: wait;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference as per performance is too minor to even matter.

The cursor only could be seen once over anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best to apply the cursor style to the element.

Check **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vzapasbw/)** (and probably best to do so using Chrome).

Each button creates 500,000 paragraphs with no spacing between them:

```
JS:
function paragraphs(className) {
  var s= '';
  for(var i = 0 ; i < 500000 ; i++) {
    s+= '<p class="'+className+'"></p>';
  }
  document.querySelector('div').innerHTML= s;
}

CSS:
p {
 margin: 0;
}
```

The first button applies the cursor on the element, the second applies it on the hover pseudo class.

The cursor should *not* change when moving between paragraphs.  However, it does when the style is applied on the pseudo class.